# How to write a a self replacing/updating binary?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am trying to write a C program which may lookup a url and incase a new version of it is avaiable it should be able to update itself.

The method i have tried:

1. Forkout a new process to Download the new binary say BINARY.tmp, code i am using to forkout the is:

   ```
   int
   forkout_cmd(char *cmdstr) {
     pid_t pid;
     char *cmd[4];

     cmd[0] = "/bin/bash";
     cmd[1] = "-c";
     cmd[2] = cmdstr;
     cmd[3] = NULL;

     pid = vfork();
     if( pid == -1 ) {
       logmsg("Forking for upgradation failed.");
       return -1;
     }else if( pid == 0 ){
       /* we are in child process */
       execvp(cmd[0], cmd);
       logmsg("execl failed while executing upgradation job.");
     }else{
       /* need not to wait for the child to complete. */
       wait(NULL);
     }
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. The new process tries to overwrite the original BINARY

   for example you may consider the routine which forks out may be doing:

   ```
   forkout_cmd("wget -O BINARY.tmp https://someurl.com/BINARY_LATEST; /bin/mv -f BINARY.tmp BINARY");
   ```

But, the overwriting fails since the original binary is still in execution and hence busy on disk, can somebody provide me some suggestions here to overcome this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure it is a good idea. Leave the update to the responsibility of package manager...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rename the currently running binary to something else, write the new binary, run it, then delete the renamed binary later.

Comment: Can a C program delete itself ?

Comment: @akm: On Linux any binary can delete itself, as long as it has sufficient priviliges.

Comment: @akm: Under Linux, yes (at least, kind of). It cannot _truly_ delete the binary, but it can replace the link and orphan the actual file (which effectively deletes it after the process exited).

Comment: The way I do it is overwrite the current binary with an updated one, and show the user a message, something like: "The program has been updated, restart it for the changes to take effect". Makes sense for GUI apps. Not so much for console applications, of course.

Comment: The new one can delete the old one (on Windows you can't delete it while it runs).

Answer (score 6):

I would save `binary.tmp` to the same directory as the executable, verify its checksum/signature (whatever it takes to be 100% sure no error occurred), and then [atomically rename](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) it to the executable's name.

Under Linux, this can be done while the program is running, no problem whatsoever (you are only changing the link, the underlying file persists while mappings to it are open, that is until the program is closed or restarted).

I would under no circumstances rename the original file or even overwrite it. This is unsafe and not necessary. You can do all "unsafe" operations that could fail on the temp file before touching the original. If anything goes wrong in the atomic rename, you still have the working original.

Then prompt the user to restart the program (if interactive) and done.